# Checkbox unchecks on Dialog start in Android

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a checkbox in a custom dialog I've created. The onClick function seems to work fine but the box reverts to unchecked if I close the dialog and re-open. I'm assuming something is getting refreshed and not remembering the state of the checkbox. How do I get it to preserve the check?

Here's my dialog:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog() {
     AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

     LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
     View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popuplayout, null);
     helpBuilder.setView(layout);

     helpBuilder.setPositiveButton(
       "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Close the dialog
            }
        });
        AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
        helpDialog.show();
        return helpBuilder.create();

}
```

Checkbox method:

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view){
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.check_devices:
            if(checked)
                abc();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would still need to set the CheckBox to checked when you create the Dialog.

### Edit

You can override `onPrepareDialog` in which you can search for the CheckBox (via `findViewById(R.id.yourCheckBox)`) and then call `setChecked(boolean value)` on it.

```
@Override
public void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog){
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.yourCheckBox);
    cb.setChecked(valueToSet); // Could be a global variable, or always true if that is what you need.

    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
}
```

Keep in mind that this is a deprecated method, but it get's the message across (I hope).

Comment: Where do I implement this? In the dialog?

Comment: Yes I figured I need to use `CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.yourCheckBox);
    cb.setChecked(valueToSet);` How does onPrepareDialog get called? Do I call this method in my create dialog?

Comment: It is automatically called in the dialogs lifecycle. It is called after `onCreateDialog`. You could add a check to see if the ID that is passed as a parameter is what you gave to `showDialog(dialogID)`.

Comment: There's seems to be a few ways to go about this. My original way didn't work because     `CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.yourCheckBox);` would always throw a NullPointer because there's no layout specified. I shouldn't be using another setContentView

Comment: I've never had `findViewById()` throwing a NullPointer... Are you sure you are using an existing id to pass to it?

Comment: Yes. R.id.check_devices is my check box and the layout is popuplayout.xml. I'm inflating the layout in the create dialog. Can I use the inflated layout to call R.id.check_devices? It doesn't seem to know what the layout is.

Comment: Try calling `findViewById` on the passed Dialog parameter.

Comment: Sorry ,whats the passed dialog parameter?

Comment: The Dialog parameter, from the onPrepareDialog function that we're talking about.

Comment: This did it: (CheckBox)layout.findViewById(R.id.yourCheckBox. I needed to reference the inflated layout. I couldn't get onPrepareDiualog to run. I'll have to look into it some more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to save the `Checkbox` as checked or not. Then you can check this preference when the `Dialog` is opened and use the `setChecked()` method to check the box accordingly.

This will save the value for the `Checkbox` persistently since I'm guessing this is something that you want saved even when you leave the app.

[SharedPreferences Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

The first link I posted has a really good example of how to get started using it. You will save the preference when the `Checkbox` is checked/unchecked then read the preference everytime you open the `Dialog`